# Verilog in Vivado - DRC MDRV-1 Multiple Driver Nets Error

Tags: verilog, vivado, drc

I am writing code that behaves as a rudimentary register file. I have created the register file as a module reg_file.v. The code instantiates a module, describing a register with loading capabilities, using generate with a simple 'for' loop.

When trying to implement the register module, I get the forementioned error. Here is the register module:

```
    `timescale 1ns / 1ps

module simple_register_load
    #(parameter N = 4)(
        input clk,
        input load,
        input [N - 1:0] I,
        output [N - 1:0] Q        
    );
    
    reg [N - 1:0] Q_reg, Q_next;
    
    always @(posedge clk)
    begin
        Q_reg <= Q_next;
    end
    
    // Next State logic
    always @(load, I, Q_reg)
    begin
        if (load)
            Q_next = I;
        else
            Q_next = Q_reg;
    end
    
    // Output logic
    assign Q = Q_reg;
endmodule
```

Within the "Next State Logic" the line associated with Q_reg <= Q_next gets flagged for the error.

```
always @(posedge clk)
    begin
        Q_reg <= Q_next;
    end
```

I have searched the forums and have found others with similar issues, and they all point to modifying an output in multiple 'always' statements. But here, I only modify Q_reg in one of the 'always' blocks. Q_next is also only modified in one 'always' block. I am puzzled.

This is the register file module code for reference:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module reg_file
    #(parameter N = 4, BITS = 4)(
    input clk,
    input [N - 1:0] address_w, address_r, //write address, read address
    input WE, //write enable
    input [BITS - 1:0] data_w, // write data
    output [BITS - 1:0] data_r // read data
    
    ,
    input read_write_sel
    );  
    
    wire [2**N - 1:0] address_w_dec, address_r_dec;
    wire [BITS - 1:0] reg_data;
    
    // WRITE PORT
    decoder_generic #(.N(N)) write_decoder( // N x 2^N decoder
        .w(address_w),
        .en(WE),
        .y(address_w_dec)
    );
    
    // READ PORT
    decoder_generic #(.N(N)) read_decoder( // N x 2^N decoder
        .w(address_r),
        .en(~WE),
        .y(address_r_dec)
    );

    // REGISTERS
    genvar k;
    generate
        for(k = 0; k < 2**N; k = k + 1)
        begin: register
            simple_register_load #(.N(BITS)) R(
                .clk(clk),
                .load(address_w_dec[k]),
                .I(data_w),
                .Q(reg_data)
            );
            assign data_r = address_r_dec[k] ? reg_data : 'bz;
        end
    endgenerate
    
endmodule
```

The errors if I run for N = 1 (generate 2^N = 2 registers):

> [DRC MDRV-1] Multiple Driver Nets: Net nolabel_line34/register[1].R/Q[1] has multiple drivers: nolabel_line34/register[0].R/Q_reg_reg[1]/Q, and nolabel_line34/register[1].R/Q_reg_reg[1]/Q.

> [DRC MDRV-1] Multiple Driver Nets: Net nolabel_line34/register[1].R/Q[2] has multiple drivers: nolabel_line34/register[0].R/Q_reg_reg[2]/Q, and nolabel_line34/register[1].R/Q_reg_reg[2]/Q.

> [DRC MDRV-1] Multiple Driver Nets: Net nolabel_line34/register[1].R/Q[3] has multiple drivers: nolabel_line34/register[0].R/Q_reg_reg[3]/Q, and nolabel_line34/register[1].R/Q_reg_reg[3]/Q.

I feel like there is a really simple issue that I am missing, and I would be very grateful if someone could point it out.

Comment: You have all of your registers tied directly to the same output bus, `reg_data`. This needs to be a separate bus for each instance of a register.

Comment: One way to fix this is to put the declaration for `reg_data` inside the generate loop. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22200666/2060012) for an example.

Comment: Thank you [Dave Tweed](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/11683/dave-tweed) for all the helpful tips. What I ended up using for this particular case was your suggestion of generating the wire each cycle in the for loop, and the error disappeared. I had no idea you could generate new wire like that (I’m in the very early stages of learning verilog) It ends up using a lot of wire, but as you’ve already explained, there are much simpler ways than my current rendition. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a bank of registers, it's really much simpler to use an array. Something like this:

```vhdl
module register_bank #(
  parameter AWP = 3,       // address width parameter
  parameter DWP = 3        // data width parameter
) (
  input wire           clk,        // write clock
  input wire   [AWP:0] addr_w,     // write address
  input wire   [AWP:0] addr_r,     // read address
  input wire           we,         // write enable
  input wire   [DWP:0] din,        // write data
  output wire  [DWP:0] q           // read data
);

  reg [DWP:0] mem [0:2**(AWP+1)-1];

  always @(posedge clk) if (we) mem[addr_w] <= din;
  assign q = mem[addr_r];

endmodule
```

Not too long ago, I used an extended version of this module to create a dual-port register array for a custom CPU design. This mapped directly to a dual-port hardware block RAM (BRAM) on the FPGA that I was using.